# How to integrate a function in R?

Tags: r, math

In R, I am trying to integrate the following function and verify that it is a pdf, as well as get the expected value and variance.... though I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

The function that needs to be verified is: f(x) = (x/4)*e^((-x^2)/8), x >= 0.

So far, I only have:

```
fun = expression((x/4)*e^((-x^2)/8))
integrate(fun,0,Inf)
```

It states error with the code above...

I know to get the expected value would be:

```
mean(x)
```

and the variance would be:

```
vcov(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function into integrate

```
fun = function(x) {(x/4)*exp((-x^2)/8)}
integrate(fun,0,10)

# Mean
fun2 = function(x) {x*fun(x)}
integrate(fun2,0,Inf)

# Variance
fun3 = function(x){(x-2.506628)^2 * fun(x)}
integrate(fun3,0,Inf)
```

Comment: might be a dumb question, but e is written as "exp" in R?

Comment: Yes :) It is a function exp( )

Comment: I tried to use the vcov() and mean() functions on the expressions and it didn't work... would you happen to know why?

Comment: The integrate() function takes an upper and lower limit of integration - so we don't really supply an x value. Since what you have supplied is a probability density function, you could technically find the mean for it as well. I added the code for that.